# MySQL - Incorporar una base de datos nueva a una replicacion Bidireccional

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estos dias estuve trabajando con MySQL para lograr una replicacion bidireccional que me permite principalmente sincronizar dos bases de datos, de esta manera solucione gran parte del problema con el que me estaba enfrentando. Sin embargo, ahora tengo otro:
¿De que manera puedo incoporar una tercera base de datos a la replicacion y que mantenga la relacion bidireccional? (En este caso pasaria a ser tridireccional, creo).

Para pasar en limpio, tengo tres bases de datos y necesito que esten sincronizadas, logre hacerlo con dos mediante una relacion master-master pero ahora necesito incorporar una tercera base de datos y que siga funcionando de la misma manera.

Por lo que vi con el auto_increment lo que hace actualmente es darle los pares a una BBDD y los impares a la otra, ¿Como funcionaria esto si incorporo una tercera BBDD?

Comment: Actualizacion: Acabo de notar que una posible solucion es utilizando la configuracion de MySQL "auto-increment-increment" y "auto-increment-offset".
De esta manera puedo configurar en auto-incremente de cada BBDD de tal manera que no se choquen los ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre encontrar la solucion a este problema, voy a resumir los pasos de manera sencilla para ayudar a posibles personas que tengan este incoveniente en un futuro.

1.- Lo primero es asegurarse de tener una version igual o superior a MySQL 5.7, en mi caso estaba trabajando sin darme cuenta con 5.5 y al parecer no existia uno de los comandos que se necesitan para llevar a cabo esto.

2.- El segundo paso es asegurarse de que la configuracion sea la adecuada para lo que vamos a hacer, les dejo a continuacion la configuracion del archivo "my.ini" de mi servidor A

*Recuerden que "server-id" no puede repetirse.*

```
[mysqld]

server-id = 1
log-bin = mysql-bin.log
binlog-ignore-db=information_schema
replicate-ignore-db=information_schema
relay-log="mysql-relay-log"
auto-increment-increment = 3
auto-increment-offset = 1
binlog_do_db = vla_gestion
master-info-repository=TABLE
relay-log-info-repository=TABLE
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
```

En mi caso el resto de servidores mantienen la misma configuracion a excepcion de "auto-increment-offset", ya que estos valores deberian ser: Para servidor B = 2 y para Servidor C = 3. Esto nos va a garantizar que los ID de las filas que agreguemos no se choquen al sincronizar.

*En este punto es recomendable reiniciar el servicio de MySQL.*

3.- El tercer paso es crear los usuarios en cada maquina, lo mejor seria dejar todos con el mismo nombre y contraseña para evitar confusiones.

```
CREATE USER 'replicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '[replicator_password]';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '[replicator_password]';
```

4.- Ahora viene la parte mas dificil de la replicacion, debemos conectar todas las bases de datos entre si.
Voy a explicar conceptualmente que debemos hacer y despues les mostrare el codigo.
La manera en la que vamos a conectar las 3 bases de datos es a traves de algo que MySQL nombre "channels". Con esto vamos a poder conectarnos a mas de un usuario simultaneamente desde un mismo servidor. Por lo tanto voy a ejemplificar con el servidor A, que deberia conectarse al C y B.

Lo primero seria detener nuestro slave.

```
stop slave;
```

Ahora vamos a conectarnos al servidor B, para ello debo consultar el estado del master en dicho servidor. Por lo tanto en el servidor B vamos a correr esta linea:

```
show master status
```

Con esta informacion vamos a volver al servidor A y vamos a utilizar toda esta sentencia para realizar la conexion

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'ip_servidor', 
MASTER_USER = 'usuario', 
MASTER_PASSWORD = 'constraseña', 
MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000001', 
MASTER_LOG_POS = 107 
FOR CHANNEL 'master-2'
```

Asegurense de poner bien la ip, el usuario y la contraseña.
En "MASTER_LOG_FILE" y en "MASTER_LOG_POS" vamos a completarlo con la informacion que nos brindo la sentencia hecha en el servidor B.

Por ultimo levantamos de nuevo el slave con:

```
start slave;
```

Recuerden la importancia de **asignar un canal**, de esta manera cuando conectemos a otra maquina lo que haremos seria cambiar el canal, a 'master-3' por ejemplo. Asi no perdemos la conexion anterior.

Para finalizar lo que faltaria seria asegurarse de que esten hechas todas las conexiones, en este caso serian:
A con B y C,
B con A y C,
C con A y B.

Y listo, esto seria todo para tener una base sincronizada master-master-master en MySQL. Espero que haya quedado todo claro.